# Was Iyov rewarded for passing his first test?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, reward-punishment, job-iyov-book-of, satan, test

In Iyov chapter 1 Satan proposes to God to test Iyov's fidelity to God by striking Iyov's possessions. God agrees and Iyov loses essentially everything. At the end of chapter 1 and again in chapter 2 God indicates that Iyov withstood this test

> וְעֹדֶ֙נּוּ֙ מַחֲזִ֣יק בְּתֻמָּת֔וֹ [Iyov] still keeps his integrity
>    (2:3)

According to some commentaries (Ramban, Malbim) God tests righteous people in order to provide them with additional reward/goodness when those people pass their tests.

My question is based on the assumption that the purpose of this test of Iyov was more than just to prove Satan wrong, but to also reward Iyov for passing the test. Furthermore, I understand that Satan proposes a second test and that in the end God does reward Iyov for passing that test. It is not clear to me, and I have not seen any commentaries which weigh in on this point, if the reward Iyov receives at the end of the book is for passing **both** tests, or merely the latter one.

It seems to me from the simple reading of the text that the reward was for the latter test only. If all the aforementioned is correct then I am compelled to ask what, if any, reward Iyov received for passing the first test. And, should the answer be none, then why was he not rewarded?

Comment: "from the simple reading of the text" can you elaborate on that Which verses indicate that?